# Prevent Bluetooth device idle and disconnection in android service

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, android-service, keep-alive

I'm running a service in android (API 19) that play an audio file every 5 minutes. After 5 minutes the service bring up an activity(the graphic interfaces for the user) to alert the user and wait for an input (a specific key pressed on a bluettoth keyboard). Everything is working fine except:
Between one timer and another, the bluetooth keyboard disconnects becouse for 5 minutes there is no input. Everytime I have to press a key to reconect the keyboard and then press the specific key to restart the countdown.
Is there anyway to keep alive the connection with the keyboard,a sort of ping or keepalive?
thank you